# How to display an aggregation of an object that is connected to another object?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, aggregation, facebook-timeline

I've set up these 2 **objects**:

- *Book*
- *Author*

A book has an **author** field.

I have one **action**:

- *Read*

I have 2 **aggregations**:

- Recently read books
- Favorite authors

**The *Favorite authors* aggregation is set up to show *author* objects on the *read* action.**

I posted a story to my Timeline: *Felipe read "some book"*, **but it only shows the *Recently read books* aggregation and not the *Favorite authors***.

How am I suppose to set up the aggregation for *Favorite authors*?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this by now? I'm looking at [a very similar problem](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11346001/how-can-i-aggregate-opengraph-objects-that-are-connected-to-another-object-in-th). Thanks!

Comment: No, I still haven't find a solution, sorry.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for answering after such a long time, though!

Answer (score 0):

If the aggregation is setup correctly (you can test this by adding sample objects and actions in the aggregation configuration) then it will show up when there is enough data to build the aggregation.

As not all aggregations show on Timeline for all people, you can see how it appears for you by looking at your app timeline view. You can find this at https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE

Comment: Hi Simon. I have already tested the aggregation by publishing plenty of "read" actions for different "books" (each book has one "author" field). But the only aggregation shown is the "Recently read books" and not the "Favorite authors". I've tested this with both sample URLs provided by Facebook and live data from my website. Any ideas?