# Facebook timeline aggregation only shows

Tags: facebook-opengraph, aggregation, facebook-timeline

I've set up this object:

Track

I have 2 actions:

Nominate

Vote

I have 2 aggregations:

Nominated Tracks

Voted Tracks

I posted several votes and nominations to my timeline but the aggregation only ever shows votes. I have seen several posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878430/how-to-display-an-aggregation-of-an-object-that-is-connected-to-another-object) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520224/getting-only-1-aggregation-on-timeline-and-not-a-report)) with the same issue but none of them have got valid answers. When I look at the facebook documentation it shows an example aggregation with multiple lists but it won't work for me!

Can anyone please help?